# Multiple keys on keyCode event on a canvas - JS

Tags: javascript, canvas

Just beginning with some keyboard control for JS.
I've got single key use down to make a ball go left/up/down/right with the arrow keys but wondering though how to write to go diagonal with the left and up key pressed down together.

Ive tried this and it doesn't work.

```
if (e.keyCode==37 && e.keyCode==39) {
    mx = -2;
    my = -2;
}
```

Not to sure how to write it.

Comment: A variable (`e.keyCode`) can only have one value at a time, not two, so that clearly can't work. What type of event are you listening for here? keydown, keyup, keypress?

Comment: Ahh okay.  
It is a keydown event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
   mx = -2;
}
if(e.keyCode == 39){
   my = -2;
}
```

Note the absence of `else`.

Comment: I got rid of the else statements but it didn't change anything.
I should note that it is not a manual use, once i hit the left key it will move left til it rebounds off the side and goes right.

I then changed it to manual and it also changed nothing though.

Comment: Look at this. http://jsbin.com/faxopowiba/1/edit?html,js,output .... You should change (rethink) the structure of you code to move diagonally.

Comment: Thanks for that, ill look at changing the way its done, Haven't done this before, i'll look into the addEventListener too and try use it. 
Great help though

Comment: Do you have an email I could shoot you few a few questions?
I'm trying to run it in a text editor (Sublime3) and can't get it too work.